# How to format \today to the 'DD MMM YYYY' format?

Tags: formatting, date

Can anyone tell me how to format `\today` to 'DD MMM YYYY' format?

Something that gives '10 Jun 2021' would be ideal but I can work with '10 JUN 2021'.

I have looked in all the suggested answers but none of them really works.

For example the answer to this one...

[How to format \today to DD-MMM-YYYY format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380353/how-to-format-today-to-dd-mmm-yyyy-format)

...is from 2017 and doesn't seem to be compatible with this line:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

...which I am using and would prefer to leave alone unless there is a compelling reason.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which month requires 3 digits?

Comment: @Bernard The three letter abbreviation is wanted.

Comment: Please, can you make a minimal example of what you attempted to do?

Comment: @egreg: It seems I skimmed through the question and misunderstood it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2?lang=en) package?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime}
\renewcommand{\today}{\twodigit{\the\day}\ \shortmonthname[\month] \the\year}

\begin{document}
    \today
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but when I paste in (only) your exact code, I see the following error:


! LaTeX Error: Unknown option `calc' for package `datetime'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.560 \if@dt@nodate
                   
?

Apologies for the formatting of the comment- not sure how to make this better!

Comment: @BobMacrae: make sure you are using the ``datetime2`` package (not ``datetime``). I fixed this in the answer.

Comment: Interesting - I tried datetime2 but it didn't work (I will try again).  But I have just 'fixed' it by removing the [calc] - it then seemed to work with datetime.

I'm new to this and now I have to work out why '\documentclass{standalone}' is giving me a grey page - my previous attempts have all been using '\documentclass[12pt]{article}' which gives a white page.  Lots of learning!

Comment: Please replace the ``standalone`` with your actual document class (``report`` etc). This is just for testing purposes.

Comment: Ah ha!  Yes, it's working now - many thanks!  (Please note that this is with ' \usepackage{datetime}')

Comment: @BobMacrae - `datetime` and `datetime2` are two different packages.

Comment: @jak123 The text of the answer refers to `datetime2`, but the code has `datetime`.

Comment: @egreg: Indeed, I don't have a local latex distribution, and for some reason, I can't import the ``datetime2`` package in Overleaf!